# Using PageIndex, why parquet does not skip unnecessary pages?

Tags: parquet, parquet-mr

Using `parquet-mr@1.11.0`, i have a schema such as:

```
schema message page {
  required binary url (STRING);
  optional binary content (STRING);
}
```

- I'm doing a single row lookup by `url` to retrieve the associated `content`
- Rows are ordered by `url`.

The file was created with:

- parquet.block.size: 256 MB
- parquet.page.size: 10 MB

Using `parquet-tools` I was able to verify that I have indeed my column index and/or offsets for my columns:

```
column index for column url:
Boudary order: ASCENDING
                      null count  min                                       max
page-0                         0  http://materiais.(...)delos-de-curriculo  https://api.quero(...)954874/toogle_like
page-1                         0  https://api.quero(...)880/toogle_dislike  https://api.quero(...)ior-online/encceja
page-2                         0  https://api.quero(...)erior-online/todos  https://api.quero(...)nte-em-saude/todos

offset index for column url:
                          offset   compressed size       first row index
page-0                         4            224274                     0
page-1                    224278            100168                 20000
page-2                    324446             67778                 40000


column index for column content:
NONE
offset index for column content:
                          offset   compressed size       first row index
page-0                    392224            504412                     0
page-1                    896636            784246                   125
page-2                   1680882            641212                   200
page-3                   2322094            684826                   275
[... truncated ...]
page-596               256651848            183162                 53100
```

Using a reader configured as:

```java
   AvroParquetReader
      .<GenericRecord>builder(HadoopInputFile.fromPath(path, conf))
      .withFilter(FilterCompat.get(
        FilterApi.eq(
          FilterApi.binaryColumn(urlKey),
          Binary.fromString(url)
        )
      ))
      .withConf(conf)
      .build();
```

Thanks to the `column-index` and `column-offsets` I was expecting the reader to read only 2 pages:

- The one containing the `url` matching `min/max` using column index.
- then, the one containing the matching row index for `content` using offset index.

But what I see is that the reader is reading and decoding hundreds of pages (~250MB) for the `content` column, am I missing something on how PageIndex is supposed to work in parquet-mr ?

Looking a the 'loading page' and 'skipping record' log lines this is trying to build the whole record before applying the filter on `url` which, in my opinion, defeat the purpose of PageIndex.

I tried to look online and dive into how the reader works but I could not find anything.

**edit**

I found an opened PR from 2015 on `parquet-column` hinting that the current reader (at the time at least) is indeed building the whole record with all the required columns before applying the predicate:

https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/pull/288

But I fail to see, on this context, the purpose of the `column offsets`.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that, even though this is not what I was expecting reading [the specs](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/PageIndex.md), it is working as intended.

From [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1602?focusedCommentId=16866562&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16866562) I quote:

> The column url has 3 pages. Your filter finds out that page-0 matches. Based on the offset index it is translated to the row range [0..19999]. Therefore, we need to load page-0 for the column url and all the pages are in the row range [0..19999] for column content.